# Improve perfomance of loop

Tags: r, performance, loops

I am struggling to improve the performance of the below code, which is running for about 2M entries. First, the condition was inside the loop, and now it is outside, and this brought some improvements, but not enough.

Do you have any other ideas?

```r
if (Floor=="Yes") { 
  for (i in 1:length(X)){
     base_short_term[i] <- pmax(numeric_vector1[i],(1+numeric_vector2[i])^((numeric_vector3[i])/(1+numeric_vector4[i]))
  }
} else {
for (i in 1:length(X)){  
     base_short_term[i] <- pmin(numeric_vector5[i],(1+numeric_vector3[i])^((numeric_vector5[i])/(1+numeric_vector7[i]))
 }
}
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Loops are bad** in `R` and should be avoided whenever possible. Here this is the case: a vectorized operation would be far more efficient (loops lead to memory overhead) and more readable code:

```r
df <- data.frame(x1 = numeric_vector1,
                x2 = numeric_vector2,
                x3 = numeric_vector3,
                x4 = numeric_vector4,
                x5 = numeric_vector5,
                x7 = numeric_vector7)

if (Floor == "yes"){
   df$base_short_term <- pmax(df$x1, (1+df$x2)^(df$x3/df$x4))
} else{
   df$base_short_term  <- pmin(df$x5, (1+df$x3)^(df$x5/df$x7))
}
```

If loops cannot be avoided, it's better to use `lapply` or favor `Rcpp`

## Update

If vectors have different length, you will loose performance because you will need to slice first from 1 to `length(X)` or use `lapply`

### Slicing  vector

```r
df <- data.frame(x1 = numeric_vector1[seq_along(X)],
                x2 = numeric_vector2[seq_along(X)],
                x3 = numeric_vector3[seq_along(X)],
                x4 = numeric_vector4[seq_along(X)],
                x5 = numeric_vector5[seq_along(X)],
                x7 = numeric_vector7[seq_along(X)])
```

(this solution is possible because even if vectors do not have the same length, you are only using indices up to `length(X)`, for all your vectors)

### `lapply`

Really looks like your `for` loop but more efficient since it avoids creating and dumping object at each iteration

For instance, if `Floor` is `TRUE`:

```r
base_short_term <- lapply(seq_along(X), function(i), {
     pmax(numeric_vector1[i],(1+numeric_vector2[i])^((numeric_vector3[i])/(1+numeric_vector4[i]))
  })
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. What about in the initial example, length(X) was different than the length of the numeric vectors. If the length of the numeric vectors is different (one from another) it impacts somehow the response?

Comment: Here, since you only use vectors indices up to `length(X)`, you can slice them and combine in a dataframe. If you prefer not creating a dataframe, I proposed a `lapply` solution that should be more efficient than `for`